# Error al validar fecha y hora en php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un calendario para una sala de reuniones donde la gente agenda una fecha de y hora de inicio y final de la Reunión, resulta que hay gente que por error pone la fecha de inicio mayor que la fecha de final y eso no debería ser así, les muestro un ejemplo de como se almacena en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vean que el inicio es mayor que el final, estoy validando con un if pero no funciona, les dejo mi código.

```
// Si se ha enviado verificamos que no vengan vacios
if ($_POST['from']!="" AND $_POST['to']!="") 
{
    $Datein                    = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['from']));
    $Datefi                    = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['to']));

    $inicio = _formatear($Datein);
    // y la formateamos con la funcion _formatear

    $final  = _formatear($Datefi);
    
    if($inicio > $final){ //NO FUNCIONO
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Horario fuera de rango.")</script>';
    }

    $orderDate                  = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['from']));
    $inicio_normal = $orderDate;

    $orderDate2                 = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['to']));
    $final_normal  = $orderDate2;
```

Ese seria la función que formateo la fecha y hora:

```
function _formatear($fecha)
{
    return strtotime(substr($fecha, 6, 4)."-".substr($fecha, 3, 2)."-".substr($fecha, 0, 2)." " .substr($fecha, 10, 6)) * 1000;
}
```

Ya probé de todo, no hay forma de validar eso, no se donde estoy equivocándome.

```
<div class='input-group date' id='from'>
<input type='text' id="from" name="from" class="form-control"/>
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>

<div class='input-group date' id='to'>
<input type='text' name="to" id="to" class="form-control"/>
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>
```

Aquí les dejo en código completo:

```
<?php

// Definimos nuestra zona horaria
date_default_timezone_set("America/Cordoba");

// incluimos el archivo de funciones
include 'funciones.php';

// incluimos el archivo de configuracion
include 'config.php';
$query = isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query'] : NULL;
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : NULL;
// Verificamos si se ha enviado el campo con name from  




if (isset($_POST['from'])) 
    
{
        
    
    // Si se ha enviado verificamos que no vengan vacios
    if ($_POST['from']!="" AND $_POST['to']!="") 
    {
        $Datein                    = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['from']));
        $Datefi                    = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['to']));

        $inicio = _formatear($Datein);
        // y la formateamos con la funcion _formatear

        $final  = _formatear($Datefi);
        
        if($inicio > $final){ //NO FUNCIONO
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Horario fuera de rango.")</script>';
        }

        $orderDate                  = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['from']));
        $inicio_normal = $orderDate;

        $orderDate2                 = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['to']));
        $final_normal  = $orderDate2;
        
        

        // Recibimos los demas datos desde el form
        $titulo = evaluar($_POST['title']);

        // y con la funcion evaluar
        $body   = evaluar($_POST['event']);

        // reemplazamos los caracteres no permitidos
        $clase  = evaluar($_POST['class']);
        
        
    
        
    //VERIFICO SI EL REGISTRO YA EXISTE
    $q = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE class = '$clase' AND ((inicio_normal BETWEEN '$inicio_normal' AND '$final_normal') OR (final_normal BETWEEN '$inicio_normal' AND '$final_normal'))");
        
    //$q = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE class = '$clase' AND 'inicio_normal' <= $final_normal AND 'final_normal' >= $inicio_normal");
        
        
    //VERIFICO SI EL REGISTRO YA EXISTE

    //$q = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE class = '$clase' AND inicio_normal = '$inicio_normal'");
    //verificamos si el user exite con un condicional
    if(mysqli_num_rows($q) == 0){
    //mysql_num_rows <- esta funcion me imprime el numero de registro que encontro 
    // si el numero es igual a 0 es porque el registro no exite, se puede registrar
    
    // insertamos el evento
    $query="INSERT INTO agenda VALUES(null,'$titulo','$body','','$clase','$inicio','$final','$inicio_normal','$final_normal')";

    // Ejecutamos nuestra sentencia sql
    $conexion->query($query)or die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("error")</script>');
    header("Location:$base_url");   
    }
    else{
    //mysqli_close($conexion);
    // alerta de error al selecionar una sala ocupada
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Esta sala esta ocupada en este horario, por favor elija otro horario o otra sala.")</script>';
    }
              


    // Obtenemos el ultimo id insetado
    $im=$conexion->query("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM agenda");
    $row = $im->fetch_row();  
    $id = trim($row[0]);

    // para generar el link del evento
    $link = "$base_url"."descripcion_evento.php?id=$id";

    // y actualizamos su link
    $query="UPDATE agenda SET url = '$link' WHERE id = $id";

    // Ejecutamos nuestra sentencia sql
    $conexion->query($query); 

    // redireccionamos a nuestro calendario
    //header("Location:$base_url"); 
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calendario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/calendar.css">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/es-ES.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c61d55aa48.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js-sidney/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js-sidney/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js-sidney/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js-sidney/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js-sidney/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background: white;">
<div class="container"><!--CONTAINER PRINCIPAL-->
        <div class="row">
        <div class="page-header"><img class="logo" src="logo.png"><h2>RESERVAS DE SALAS BOUTIQUE</h2></div>
        <div class="page-header" id="page-header"></div>
        <div class="pull-left form-inline"><br>
           <div class="btn-group">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" data-calendar-nav="prev"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>  </button>
           <button class="btn" data-calendar-nav="today">Hoy</button>
           <button class="btn btn-primary" data-calendar-nav="next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>  </button>
           </div>
            
           <div class="btn-group">
           <button class="btn btn-warning" data-calendar-view="year">Año</button>
           <button class="btn btn-warning active" data-calendar-view="month">Mes</button>
           <button class="btn btn-warning" data-calendar-view="week">Semana</button>
           <button class="btn btn-warning" data-calendar-view="day">Dia</button>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right form-inline"><br>
        <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#add_evento'>Agendar Reunión</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        
        <div class="row">
        <div id="calendar"></div> <!-- Aqui se mostrara el calendario -->
        </div>
        
        <!--VENTANA MODAL QUE CARGA EL FORMULARIO PARA AGENDAR LA SALA-->

        <div class="modal fade" id="events-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" style="float: right;">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
        </a>
            
        <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="height: 400px">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!--VENTANA MODAL QUE CARGA EL FORMULARIO PARA AGENDAR LA SALA-->
        
</div><!--FIN CONTAINER PRINCIPAL-->
    
    <!--SCRIPT CALENDARIO-->
    <script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/calendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
                //creamos la fecha actual
                var date = new Date();
                var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
                var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getMonth()+1).toString() : (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
                var dd  = (date.getDate()).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getDate()).toString() : (date.getDate()).toString();

                //establecemos los valores del calendario
                var options = {

                    // definimos que los agenda se mostraran en ventana modal
                    modal: '#events-modal', 

                        // dentro de un iframe
                        modal_type:'iframe',    

                        //obtenemos los agenda de la base de datos
                        events_source: '<?=$base_url?>obtener_eventos.php', 

                        // mostramos el calendario en el mes
                        //view: 'month',  
                    
                        // mostramos el calendario de la semana
                        view: 'week', 

                        // y dia actual
                        day: yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd,   


                        // definimos el idioma por defecto
                        language: 'es-ES', 

                        //Template de nuestro calendario
                        tmpl_path: '<?=$base_url?>tmpls/', 
                        tmpl_cache: false,


                        // Hora de inicio
                        time_start: '07:00', 

                        // y Hora final de cada dia
                        time_end: '22:00',   

                        // intervalo de tiempo entre las hora, en este caso son 30 minutos
                        time_split: '30',    

                        // Definimos un ancho del 100% a nuestro calendario
                        width: '100%', 

                        onAfterEventsLoad: function(events)
                        {
                            if(!events)
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                            var list = $('#eventlist');
                            list.html('');

                            $.each(events, function(key, val)
                            {
                                $(document.createElement('li'))
                                .html('<a href="' + val.url + '">' + val.title + '</a>')
                                .appendTo(list);
                            });
                        },
                        onAfterViewLoad: function(view)
                        {
                            $('#page-header').text(this.getTitle());
                            $('.btn-group button').removeClass('active');
                            $('button[data-calendar-view="' + view + '"]').addClass('active');
                        },
                        classes: {
                            months: {
                                general: 'label'
                            }
                        }
                    };


                // id del div donde se mostrara el calendario
                var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar(options); 

                $('.btn-group button[data-calendar-nav]').each(function()
                {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.click(function()
                    {
                        calendar.navigate($this.data('calendar-nav'));
                    });
                });

                $('.btn-group button[data-calendar-view]').each(function()
                {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.click(function()
                    {
                        calendar.view($this.data('calendar-view'));
                    });
                });

                $('#first_day').change(function()
                {
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    value = value.length ? parseInt(value) : null;
                    calendar.setOptions({first_day: value});
                    calendar.view();
                });
            }(jQuery));
        </script>
        <!--FIN SCRIPT CALENDARIO-->
    
    
<!--INICIO DE FORMULARIO-->
<div class="modal fade" id="add_evento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar nuevo evento</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" method="post" id="form">
        <label for="from">Inicio</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='from'>
        <input type='text' id="from" name="from" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
        <br>

        <label for="to">Final</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='to'>
        <input type='text' name="to" id="to" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="contador">
        <br>

        <label for="tipo">SALA</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="class" id="tipo" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Elija la sala</option>
        <option value="SALA 1">SALA 1</option>
        <option value="SALA 2">SALA 2</option>
        <option value="SALA 3">SALA 3</option>
        </select>
        <br>
                        
        <label for="tipo">AREA</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="title" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Elija el Area</option>
        <option value="Administración">Administración</option>
        <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
        <option value="Compras">Compras</option>
        <option value="Escuelas">Escuelas</option>
        <option value="Logistica">Logistica</option>
        <option value="Mantenimiento">Mantenimiento</option>
        <option value="Operaciones">Operaciones</option>
        <option value="Recursos Humanos">Recursos Humanos</option>
        <option value="Seguridad">Seguridad</option>

        </select>
        <br>
            
        <label for="body">Descripcion</label>
        <textarea id="body" name="event" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
        
        <script>
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
  // Deberias hacer la conversion a fecha más robusta (por
  // ejemplo, que revise primero si el campo tiene un valor)
  const from = new Date($('#from').value());
  const to = new Date($('#to').value());
  if($('#from').datetimepicker>=$('#to').datetimepicker){
               alert("La fecha de inicio debe ser menor a la fecha de fin");
          }
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
        </script>
            
      <!--SCRIPT FECHA Y HORA -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $('#from').datetimepicker({
            /* language: 'es',*/
            sideBySide: true,
            minDate:new Date()
             });

           $('#to').datetimepicker({
              /*   language: 'es',*/
              sideBySide: true,
              minDate:new Date()
               
             });
          
        });
        </script>
        <!--FIN SCRIPT FECHA Y HORA -->
            

                        
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Agregar</button>
        </form>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
                
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<!--FIN DE FORMULARIO-->
            
            
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No uso funcion, uso el if que esta arriba en la pregunta

Comment: Entonces no tienes nada que compare las variables como fechas en realidad ?

Comment: Si, eso ya esta comparado, me falta saber si una fecha es mayor que otra

Comment: Ahí le deje el código completo

Comment: No me queda claro el formato que recibes en el POST; a reserva de saberlo no compares cadenas, intenta con `if( strtotime($_POST['from']) > strtotime($_POST['to']) )`

Comment: ahi lo hice, lo mismo no me respecta el if

Comment: Por eso pedi que imprimieras los datos del POST con var_dump. Para ver como llegan dentro de lo que revisamos.

Comment: No me imprimi nada, pero a su vez si se inserta en la base de datos

Comment: Algo estoy haciendo mal y no lo veo, hace 15 días que estoy con eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ACARACION - El error no era la validación de fechas.
>
> El op requeria corregir la ubicacion de las validaciones para la inserción de la query a la base de datos. Validaba las fechas correctamente, pero aun asi realizaba el ingreso de los datos. Esto debido a que tenia la inserción fuera de cualquier validación.

---

Ok, no has hecho lo que he solicitado varias veces antes, así que lo emulare...

Tu código, hasta donde se vee, funciona bien, así que lo incorrecto debe estar por parte de los inputs.

El alert salta, y muestra el error. En donde supongo que detienes el proceso, y retornar el error como tal.

Acá hice un paso a paso debugeando tu código, por como supongo que esta la data ingresada.

---

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php

$_POST['from'] = "2022-12-29 13:30:00"; //mayor
$_POST['to'] = "2022-12-29 11:17:00"; //menor

if ($_POST['from']!="" AND $_POST['to']!="") 
{
    $Datein = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['from']));
    $Datefi = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['to']));
    echo $Datein . " > " . $Datefi;
    echo "</br>";

    $inicio = _formatear($Datein);
    $final  = _formatear($Datefi);
    echo $inicio . " > " . $final;
    echo "</br>";
    
    if($inicio > $final){ //La ejecucion se debe detener por el error
        echo "Inicio es Mayor a Final // Aca se detiene la cosa"; //Alert quitado para test, pero si muestra el alert
        echo "</br>";
    }else{
        //Aca es donde el OP deberia tener el insert y el resto de las operaciones
    }

    $orderDate = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['from']));
    $inicio_normal = $orderDate; //Esta asignacion es innecesaria
    echo $orderDate;
    echo "</br>";

    $orderDate2 = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['to']));
    $final_normal  = $orderDate2; //Esta asignacion es innecesaria
    echo $orderDate2;
    echo "</br>";
}

function _formatear($fecha)
{
    return strtotime(substr($fecha, 6, 4)."-".substr($fecha, 3, 2)."-".substr($fecha, 0, 2)." " .substr($fecha, 10, 6)) * 1000;
}
```

---

Comment: Lamentablemente sigue sin funcionar, copie su código pero a mi no me funciona, me deja insertar en la base de datos una fecha de inicio mayor que la de final, le comento: el código esta todo en una sola pagina, y el formulario de inscripción esta en un modal, no se si sera ese el problema?

Comment: Ahora que miro tu codigo completo... el Insert ocurre fuera del IF de validacion de fechas, y no tienes seteado que el codigo se detenga en el momento del error... por lo que lanza el error, e inserta despues

Comment: deberia ir adentro del if en insert? a eso te refirir?

Comment: Tenias razón Excorpion, ese era el problema, el insert estaba afuera el if de validación, ahora su funciona. ;)

Comment: Me alegro, recuerda aceptar la respuesta y darle +1 para aumentarme el ego XD

Comment: Ya lo hice. Gracias